# chatterbot python3 OperationalError: no such column: statement.conversation while training chatbot

Tags: python, python-3.x, chatterbot, operationalerror

I have an issue when *chatbot.get_response()* and (exactly the same problem) when *trainer.tain()* on a list of english strings. It says

[*OperationalError: no such column: statement.conversation*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pC0o4.png)

And then this one

[*OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such column: statement.conversation*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFVeJ.png)

I have the latest version of ChatterBot downloaded via git. Wanna use russian corpus after fixing this problem.

Does anyone know what can I do here? Thanks!

Comment: Based on the error, it sounds like the `conversation` column didn't get crated on the `statement` table in your database. The table should have been created automatically. If this is a new ChatterBot project you can delete the `sqlite` file and re-run your program so that it'll recreate the database tables.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! I got an answer - I just had to 'untrain' my bot and start again. Just type *chatbot.storage.drop()*